# Print Javascript Exceptions In A QWebView To The Console

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm using PyQt4 and a QWebView widget to view a webpage, but it appears as though there is a problem with my Javascript. Other browsers seem to run ok, so I would like to know if any exceptions are occurring by printing them to the console.

The code I'm using is below. What do I need to add to do this?

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtWebKit
browser = QtWebKit.QWebView()
browser.load(QtCore.QUrl("http://myurl"))
browser.show()
```

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a subclass of `QWebPage` and define the method `javaScriptConsoleMessage()`:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

class WebPage(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
    def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, msg, line, source):
        print '%s line %d: %s' % (source, line, msg)

url = 'http://localhost/test.html'
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
browser = QtWebKit.QWebView()
page = WebPage()
browser.setPage(page)
browser.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
browser.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Sample output:

```
% python qweb.py
http://localhost/test.html line 9: SyntaxError: Parse error
```

Answer (score 10):

Or you could just set the `DeveloperExtrasEnabled` setting. This will allow you to right-click the QWebView and select Inspect.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import QWebSettings

QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)
```

Comment: I wonder why this answer doesn't have so many upvotes..It so easy to use the Developer tools to debug your front end application...you have my vote friend....

Comment: Yep, it's pretty simple and straight forward.

Comment: @repzero: Might have something to do with the fact that this is a Python question, C++ code isn’t very useful then. I’ve converted the code to Python.